# java classes inheriting methods with different return value

Tags: java

if i am having two classes in java A and B that A `extends` B if I have this method in A:

```
int getmax(){};
```

and in B I have this method:

```
INTEGER getmax(){};
```

will the method in B be overridden or overloaded?
and in this case is B subtype of A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override a method and change its return value.

Also you can declare methods with the same name but different parameters but not the same name, same parameters, but different return value.

In that last case, the compiler won't know which method to use.

Answer (score 4):

If `A.getmax()` is private, you'll get two separate, unrelated methods.

If `A.getmax()` has any other access modifier (including none at all), you'll get a compilation error because the return types are not compatible.

Comment: why it would not compile?! can not I have two different methods at the same time because the signature of each one is different

Comment: @flashdisk: You can't overload on the return type. Instead of guessing, why not try compiling the code? :)

Comment: i dont have eclipes working :)

Comment: @flashdisk: You don't need to: https://ideone.com

Comment: how then I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

"The overriding method has the same name, number and type of parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides. An overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by the overridden method. This subtype is called a covariant return type." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: so when I am calling the method getmax() which one will be called and what is the return value?!

Comment: You can't even compile this code, look at the answer from Arnaud Potier.